# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/content/ServiceConnection$-CC;

Tags: android, java-8, noclassdeffounderror, android-d8

I am having this error when running my app on Android Q:

**Here's my configuration:**

> my jdk version :jdk1.8.0_221
>
> compileSdkVersion 29
>
> buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'
>
> compileOptions {
>               
> sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
>               
> targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 
> }
>
> android.useAndroidX=true
>
> android.enableJetifier=true
>
> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
>
> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip

HimalayaFmLocalAppImpl$1 is a inner class which implements android/content/ServiceConnection. And only override `onServiceConnected` and `onServiceDisconnected` methods, don't override `onBindingDied` method.

Any help is appreciated!!!

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/content/ServiceConnection$-CC;
        at com.heytap.speechassist.skill.multimedia.fm.himalaya.HimalayaFmLocalAppImpl$1.onBindingDied(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:2090)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:2126)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:238)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:983)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.content.ServiceConnection$-CC" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.heytap.speechassist-baZt4vUeYDNjgdpEqqXK7g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.heytap.speechassist-baZt4vUeYDNjgdpEqqXK7g==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.heytap.speechassist-baZt4vUeYDNjgdpEqqXK7g==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /product/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
```

Comment: I'd suggest you to look at the DEX's bytecode first, which might shed some light on root cause. Android Studio supports that using `Analyze APK` functionality.

Comment: I have checked the DEX' bytecode which is Landroid/content/ServiceConnection$-CC in fact. But I want to know why gradle build generates this error code. Maybe it is D8's bug?